# What is the Lie group defined by 2 x 2 matricies?

Tags: lie-groups

It says on Wikipedia:

"to any finite-dimensional Lie algebra over real or complex numbers, there is a corresponding connected Lie group unique up to covering."

We can turn $2 \times 2$ matricies over the reals into a Lie algebra by defining $[a, b]  = ab - ba$. Which Lie group does this define? We have

$$[a, [b, c]] +  [b, [c, a]]  + [c, [a, b]] =  0$$

for any $a, b, c$.

Comment: You are not new here, so please learn how to use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: $GL_+(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a Lie group with this Lie algebra.  By this I $2\times 2$ real matrices of positive determinant. To get uniqueness you need to say simply connected.

Comment: I edited your post to $\LaTeX$ify it and also to replace your notation $a \times b = ab - ba$ with the more conventioal $[a, b] = ab - ba$.  Hope my math edits are OK; if not, you can change them back.  But as Batomiovski says, please stick to MathJax.  It makes your questions so much more readable . . . Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is the Lie group $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb R)$. The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl(2,\mathbb R)}$ is the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Of course there are other choices. We could choose for example $G=\{A \in \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb R): \det(A)>0\}$.